# What was the original cost of a Sharps Rifle?

Tags: economy, weapons

In 1850, when the Sharps Rifle was made, how much did it cost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a [letter](https://books.google.com/books?id=XMU8AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA723&dq=sharps%20rifles%20contract%201851%20carbines&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwyOffm4PSAhVm2IMKHQDIDhYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=sharps&f=false), concerning the purchase of breach-loading rifles by the United States Army, dated May 14 1857:

> After preliminary trials of a great number of breech loading rifles
>   presented by inventors the following were reported as giving
>   sufficient evidences of merit to authorize a farther practical trial
>   in the hands of troops and orders to supply them for that purpose to
>   the extent and on the terms specified opposite to each were given by
>   this office with the sanction of the Secretarv of War viz **200 of
>   Sharp s at $30** each ordered July 28 1854 200 of Perry's at $25 each
>   ordered February 24 1855 200 of Green's at $30 each ordered May 24
>   1855 200 of Gibbs's at $30 each ordered November 17 1855 170 of
>   Merrill's at $35 each ordered July 20 1855 200 of Burnside's at $30
>   each ordered April 21 1850 201 of Syinmes's at $40 each ordered July
>   18 1855 100 of Howe's at $32 each ordered January 28 1857 200 of
>   Maynard's breech loading arms at $30 each were also recommended by
>   this office after the preliminary trial to be purchased

(emphasis mine).

This, however did not specify a production model. Note the price is what the US government paid, so may not reflect civilian prices.

The next record I find for prices is for [Sharps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharps_Rifle_Manufacturing_Company) rifles ordered during the civil War.

- The model 1859

The model 1859 was ordered for [Berdans Sharpshooters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_United_States_Sharpshooters) during the civil war. The slightly modified model,made to Berdan's specs, cost **$42.50**.

Source:[Sharpshooting in the Civil War](https://books.google.com/books?id=PILKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&dq=sharps%20rifle%20civil%20war%20cost&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA1rKl74HSAhWJ7oMKHUjUDDEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), By Major John Plaster

- The model 1874

The model 1874, the model made famous in *[Quigley Down Under](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quigley_Down_Under)*, could be bought in  1878 for **$44.00**. 
Source:[Mastering the Art of Long-Range Shooting](https://books.google.com/books?id=PYq6AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&dq=sharps%20rifle%20civil%20war%20cost&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA1rKl74HSAhWJ7oMKHUjUDDEQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=sharps%20rifle%20civil%20war%20cost&f=false), By Wayne van Zwoll

To put that in perspective, farmers in 1860 earned $10-$14 *per month*, and a [private in the Union Army](http://www.cincinnaticwrt.org/data/ccwrt_history/talks_text/moffat_soldiers_pay.html) earned $11.00-$13.00 per month.

Comment: In Blood Meridian. a character bought one in the 1850s or so and according to the book there was a huge surplus (maybe due to buffalo dying out) and they were not worth mucj.

Comment: Good answer, but the upvote from me was earned by the Quigley Down Under callback alone.

Comment: private made $13 in union army